# Uploading image to s3 bucket from node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

node.js code below

**created a bucket in 'ap-south-1' Region**
**bucket link in public u can view on** :- https://iamgroot007.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/deadpool.png

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const fs = require("fs");
const BUCKET = process.env.BUCKET;
const REGION = process.env.REGION;
const ACCESS_KEY = process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID;
const SECRET_KEY = process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
const localImage = "./ap.png";
const imageRemoteName = `catImage_${new Date().getTime()}.png`;

router.post("/image-upload", (req, res) => {
  AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: SECRET_KEY,
    region: REGION,
  });

  const s3 = new AWS.S3();

  s3.putObject({
    Bucket: BUCKET,
    Body: fs.readFileSync(localImage),
    Key: imageRemoteName,
  })
    .promise()
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(`done! - `, response);
      console.log(
        `The URL is ${s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", {
          Bucket: BUCKET,
          Key: imageRemoteName,
        })}`
      );
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("failed:", err);
    });
```

Getting Error :-

> message:
> 'Inaccessible host: `s3.ap-south-1\'. This service may not be available in the` ap-south-1,' region.',
> code: 'UnknownEndpoint',
> region: 'ap-south-1,',
> hostname: 's3.ap-south-1',
> retryable: true,
> originalError:
> { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND s3.ap-south-1 s3.ap-south-1:443
> at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
> message: 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND s3.ap-south-1 s3.ap-south-1:443',
> errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
> code: 'NetworkingError',
> syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
> hostname: 's3.ap-south-1',
> host: 's3.ap-south-1',
> port: 443,
> region: 'ap-south-1,',
> retryable: true,
> time: 2020-09-11T19:08:30.062Z },
> time: 2020-09-11T19:08:30.062Z }

Comment: Does the hostname in the error message (`s3.ap-south-1\\`) literally have that trailing slash or is that a copy/paste error of some sort on your part? Have you verified, by logging, that your BUCKET and REGION environment variable values are actually correct?

Comment: Yes my bucket and region name is correct and the error is been pasted as it is

Comment: Unrelated to your connectivity issue, the way you are initializing `imageRemoteName` is wrong. You should move it into the function handler. The way you have written it, multiple uploads may be written to the same cat file if the Lambda function is warm when invoked (in which case the initialization code outside of the function handler is not re-run).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will update as u said

Comment: Actually maybe this is not even running on Lambda, but the comment remains that you should init `imageRemoteName` in the upload route handler. Can you run the awscli on the same system? Maybe test the awscli uploading an object to that same ap-south-1 bucket using the same BUCKET and REGION environment variables in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

There was 2 mistakes
1> In .env folder i was having ',' after secretKey,accessKey and Bucket name
2> i did not use multer middleware for accepting the incoming FormData

Working code for uploading image is:-

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: SECRET_KEY,
});

const storage = multer.memoryStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, "");
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage }).single("image");

router.post("/image-upload", upload, (req, res) => {
  let fileName = req.file.originalname.split(".");
  const myFileType = fileName[fileName.length - 1];
  const Key = `shopLogo/${uuidv4()}.${myFileType}`;
  console.log(fileName, myFileType, Key, BUCKET);
  const params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET,
    Key,
    Body: req.file.buffer,
  };

  s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    res.status(200).send(data);
  });
});
```